# Why whitespace is not the delimiter for input()?

Tags: python, input, delimiter

I am new to [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29). In Python `input()` and `raw_input()` reads line by line whereas in C/C++ the default delimiter for reading inputs is whitespace.

I know I can use `split()` to get the list. Is there any significance of not having whitespace as the default input delimiter?

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2 `input()` accepts a line of code from the user, executes it, and returns the result -- so reading line by line instead of word by word is only significant in that it makes that process much easier.  `raw_input` was a twin to `input`, except it did not try to evaluate what was entered, it just returned it as a `str`.

Running user input is also very dangerous, which is why it was removed in Python 3, and `raw_input` took `input`'s place.

**Python 2**:

```
--> test_var = input('enter a number: ')
# user enters "71 + 9" (without quotes), Python tries to run the text entered
--> test_var
# 80
--> type(test_var)
# <type 'int'>

--> test_var = raw_input('enter another number: ')
# user enters "99 - 9", Python simply gives back the string '99 - 9'
--> test_var
 # '99 - 9'
--> type(test_var)
# <type 'str'>

--> test_var = input('enter something')
# user enters "howdy" (without the quotes)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'howdy' is not defined
```

Comment: I can't understand "In Python 2, input() will try to eval the text entered by the user, and raw_input() will not". If you don't mind could you please explain briefly ?

Comment: @Venkatesh `input()` will call `eval()` on what the user enters. So if you enter, say, `22+5`, `input()` will return `27`.
On the other hand, `raw_input()` for `22+5` will yield `"22+5"` instead.

Comment: @ArdaXi: Thanks, put that in my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, input default type is `string` and in a `string` object's value, whitespaces are allowed (e.g `s = "Bob Fred"`). `split(delim)` is for splitting string object by a specified delimiter (again, default delimiter is whitespace here if you leave the `delim` argument empty).

I think this is a default choice (design decision) as you will soon realise that converting string to integer, float, etc. type of data types is pretty trivial.

Comment: input does not have "a default type" of string.  It always returns strings. Period.

Comment: @NedBatchelder    yes, it is a design decision, which might very well change at some point in a future release.

Comment: No, it won't.  The point of `raw_input` (python 2) / `input` (python 3) is to return strings.  We will not be changing that.

Comment: @EthanFurman     Very well. I am sure there is a very good reason for this - but this may be a different chapter.